# Mysql optimization Myisam

Tags: mysql, linux, optimization

I have an eCommerce (CS-Cart) based on Mysql (MyIsam) with about 3,000 items and a database size of 700MB and index size of 247MB. In the last month for a reason i don't know the performances have fallen down and are very inconstant. I optimized the DB as I usually do and tried to change some Mysql variables according with some suggestion I found over the internet.

The dedicated server is quite old Cpu dual core pentium E2180 6GB RAM 160GB SATA

**and this is the screenshot of the top command**

[image]

**An these are the Mysql variables**

auto_increment_increment

1

auto_increment_offset

1

automatic_sp_privileges

ON

back_log

50

basedir

/usr/

bdb_cache_size

8384512

bdb_home

/var/lib/mysql/

bdb_log_buffer_size

262144

bdb_logdir

bdb_max_lock

10000

bdb_shared_data

OFF

bdb_tmpdir

/tmp/

binlog_cache_size

32768

bulk_insert_buffer_size

8388608

character_set_client

utf8

character_set_connection

utf8

character_set_database

latin1

character_set_filesystem

binary

character_set_results

utf8

character_set_server

latin1

character_set_system

utf8

character_sets_dir

/usr/share/mysql/charsets/

collation_connection

utf8_general_ci

collation_database

latin1_swedish_ci

collation_server

latin1_swedish_ci

completion_type

0

concurrent_insert

1

connect_timeout

10

datadir

/var/lib/mysql/

date_format

%Y-%m-%d

datetime_format

%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s

default_week_format

0

delay_key_write

ON

delayed_insert_limit

100

delayed_insert_timeout

300

delayed_queue_size

1000

div_precision_increment

4

keep_files_on_create

OFF

engine_condition_pushdown

OFF

expire_logs_days

0

flush

OFF

flush_time

0

ft_boolean_syntax

```
-><()~*:""&|
```

ft_max_word_len

84

ft_min_word_len

4

ft_query_expansion_limit

20

ft_stopword_file

(built-in)

group_concat_max_len

1024

have_archive

NO

have_bdb

YES

have_blackhole_engine

NO

have_compress

YES

have_community_features

YES

have_profiling

YES

have_crypt

YES

have_csv

NO

have_dynamic_loading

YES

have_example_engine

NO

have_federated_engine

NO

have_geometry

YES

have_innodb

YES

have_isam

NO

have_merge_engine

YES

have_ndbcluster

NO

have_openssl

DISABLED

have_ssl

DISABLED

have_query_cache

YES

have_raid

NO

have_rtree_keys

YES

have_symlink

YES

hostname

ltfs676.aus.us.siteprotect.com

init_connect

init_file

init_slave

innodb_additional_mem_pool_size

1048576

innodb_autoextend_increment

8

innodb_buffer_pool_awe_mem_mb

0

innodb_buffer_pool_size

8388608

innodb_checksums

ON

innodb_commit_concurrency

0

innodb_concurrency_tickets

500

innodb_data_file_path

ibdata1:10M:autoextend

innodb_data_home_dir

innodb_adaptive_hash_index

ON

innodb_doublewrite

ON

innodb_fast_shutdown

1

innodb_file_io_threads

4

innodb_file_per_table

OFF

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

1

innodb_flush_method

innodb_force_recovery

0

innodb_lock_wait_timeout

50

innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog

OFF

innodb_log_arch_dir

innodb_log_archive

OFF

innodb_log_buffer_size

1048576

innodb_log_file_size

5242880

innodb_log_files_in_group

2

innodb_log_group_home_dir

./

innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct

90

Variable_name

Value

innodb_max_purge_lag

0

innodb_mirrored_log_groups

1

innodb_open_files

300

innodb_rollback_on_timeout

OFF

innodb_support_xa

ON

innodb_sync_spin_loops

20

innodb_table_locks

ON

innodb_thread_concurrency

8

innodb_thread_sleep_delay

10000

innodb_use_legacy_cardinality_algorithm

ON

interactive_timeout

28800

join_buffer_size

131072

key_buffer_size

367001600

key_cache_age_threshold

300

key_cache_block_size

1024

key_cache_division_limit

100

language

/usr/share/mysql/english/

large_files_support

ON

large_page_size

0

large_pages

OFF

lc_time_names

en_US

license

GPL

local_infile

OFF

locked_in_memory

OFF

log

OFF

log_bin

OFF

log_bin_trust_function_creators

OFF

log_error

/var/log/mysqld.log

log_queries_not_using_indexes

OFF

log_slave_updates

OFF

log_slow_queries

OFF

log_warnings

1

long_query_time

10

low_priority_updates

OFF

lower_case_file_system

OFF

lower_case_table_names

0

max_allowed_packet

1048576

max_binlog_cache_size

4294963200

max_binlog_size

1073741824

max_connect_errors

10

max_connections

100

max_delayed_threads

20

max_error_count

64

max_heap_table_size

16777216

max_insert_delayed_threads

20

max_join_size

4294967295

max_length_for_sort_data

1024

max_prepared_stmt_count

16382

max_relay_log_size

0

max_seeks_for_key

4294967295

max_sort_length

1024

max_sp_recursion_depth

0

max_tmp_tables

32

max_user_connections

50

max_write_lock_count

4294967295

multi_range_count

256

myisam_data_pointer_size

6

myisam_max_sort_file_size

2146435072

myisam_mmap_size

4294967295

myisam_recover_options

OFF

myisam_repair_threads

1

myisam_sort_buffer_size

8388608

myisam_stats_method

nulls_unequal

net_buffer_length

16384

net_read_timeout

30

net_retry_count

10

net_write_timeout

60

new

OFF

old_passwords

OFF

open_files_limit

20000

optimizer_prune_level

1

optimizer_search_depth

62

pid_file

/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

plugin_dir

port

3306

preload_buffer_size

32768

profiling

OFF

profiling_history_size

15

protocol_version

10

query_alloc_block_size

8192

query_cache_limit

1048576

query_cache_min_res_unit

4096

query_cache_size

0

query_cache_type

ON

query_cache_wlock_invalidate

OFF

query_prealloc_size

8192

range_alloc_block_size

4096

read_buffer_size

131072

read_only

OFF

read_rnd_buffer_size

262144

relay_log

relay_log_index

relay_log_info_file

relay-log.info

relay_log_purge

ON

relay_log_space_limit

0

rpl_recovery_rank

0

secure_auth

OFF

secure_file_priv

server_id

0

skip_external_locking

ON

Variable_name

Value

skip_networking

OFF

skip_show_database

OFF

slave_compressed_protocol

OFF

slave_load_tmpdir

/tmp/

slave_net_timeout

3600

slave_skip_errors

OFF

slave_transaction_retries

10

slow_launch_time

2

socket

/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

sort_buffer_size

2097144

sql_big_selects

ON

sql_mode

sql_notes

ON

sql_warnings

OFF

ssl_ca

ssl_capath

ssl_cert

ssl_cipher

ssl_key

storage_engine

MyISAM

sync_binlog

0

sync_frm

ON

system_time_zone

CDT

table_cache

64

table_lock_wait_timeout

50

table_type

MyISAM

thread_cache_size

0

thread_stack

196608

time_format

%H:%i:%s

time_zone

SYSTEM

timed_mutexes

OFF

tmp_table_size

33554432

tmpdir

/tmp/

transaction_alloc_block_size

8192

transaction_prealloc_size

4096

tx_isolation

REPEATABLE-READ

updatable_views_with_limit

YES

version

5.0.95

version_bdb

Sleepycat Software: Berkeley DB 4.1.24: (December ...

version_comment

Source distribution

version_compile_machine

i386

version_compile_os

redhat-linux-gnu

wait_timeout

28800

Can anybody please help me tuning the system?

Comment: Do a search for slow query log

Comment: Find the slow queries, provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 0):

I have been used below parameters in my running 70 TPS system.
Your buffer size should not externally large. It slow down the query response.

```
#MY.CNF
skip-locking
skip-innodb
key_buffer = 64M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
[mysqldump]
  quick
   max_allowed_packet = 16M
[mysql]
   no-auto-rehash
    # Remove the next comment character if you are not familiar with SQL
    #safe-updates
[isamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[myisamchk]
key_buffer = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M
[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
    myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
    thread_cache_size = 8
    query_cache_size = 256M
    query_cache_limit = 32M
    tmp_table_size = 32M
    max_heap_table_size = 32M
    bulk_insert_buffer_size = 8MB
```

Comment: `key_buffer_size` is the most important setting for MyISAM; it is already set adequately; do _not_ lower it to 64M.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I read it should be more or less equal to the index size or maximum 1/4 of the available RAM